# what's wrong with my R code?

Tags: r

I am struggling to parse contents from HTML using htmlTreeParse and XPath.
Below is the web link from where I need to extract information of "most valuable brands" and create a data frame out of it.
http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank

As a first step towards building the table, I am trying to extract the list of brands (Apple, Google, Microsoft etc. ). I am trying through below code:

```
library(XML)

htmlContent <- getURL("http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank", ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
htmlParsed <- htmlTreeParse(htmlContent, useInternal = TRUE)
output <- xpathSApply(htmlParsed, "/html/body/div/div/div/table[@id='the_list']/tbody/tr/td[@class='name']", xmlValue)
```

But its returning NULL. I am not able to find my mistake. `"/html/body/div/div/div/table[@id='the_list']/thead/tr/th"` works correctly, returning ("", "Rank", "brand" etc.)
This means path upto table is correct. But I am not able to understand what's wrong thereafter.

Comment: Scraping Forbes is a violation of their Terms of Service. You are infringing and you're asking others to infringe. Not cool.

Comment: That's just for learning. I am not gonna use any information for any benefit.

Comment: Lots of sites to learn from w/o violating ToS. This doesn't seem to be a random choice. It rarely is (lots of folks come here looking to scrape this particular data).

Comment: man this is my assignment work. I can scrape in java code within 30min if I wished so. Please help with R if you can otherwise stop preaching.